# Doctrine 2, join table two times, how to get its entities?

Tags: mysql, symfony, join, doctrine-orm

So there is a table `Users` and a left joined table `Coupons`. We want to join coupons, and then we can get by `$entity->getCoupons()`, that's simple. But there are two kind of coupons and I must join this table two times:

```
  $qb->addSelect('c')->leftJoin('x.coupons', 'c', 'WITH', 'c.type = 1');
  $qb->addSelect('c2')->leftJoin('x.coupons', 'c2', 'WITH', 'c.type = 2');
```

OK, now what? There is only one `getCoupons()`. The best would be to ask the coupons by `c`, `c2` aliases

Answer (score 1):

Just add IN statement to where clause and you will get array of objects:

```
$qb->select('c')
   ->from('User', 'u')
   ->leftJoin('u.coupons', 'c')
   ->where('c.type IN (1,2)');
```